# Share only a subset of a git repository

Tags: git

I use a git repository for my dotfiles and I'd like to share it except for some of the files (in which there are some identifiers for instance).
Is there a way to do it without creating another git repository with only the to-be-shared files ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

No. Each commit of a repository contains all the files of the commit, so a filtered view would have different commit identifiers.

You could use something like `git filter-branch`, but this in fact creates a copy of your branch, creating a new commit for each original commit (if not filtered away).

There might be a way to automate this, so you have a branch which is always seemingly identical to your original branch, but without the critical files. Then you would only push the filtered branch to some public repository.

But note that merging changes which were based on this repository back into your original one is not so easy, and likely would imply applying individual patches for each.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer. I don't think I'll do that, I'm looking for something simple and easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't need to repo your other dotfiles, just add the files you don't want to share to a .gitignore file. Do that before your first commit and those files should never be part of the repo.

If you've already repo'd your dot files, then just copy the files you don't want to share to some other directory. Run git rm .some_file on each of the files you don't want to share to remove them from the repo. Add them to the gitignore, commit and then copy them back from the other directory.

Comment: Well, unless I'm mistaken, this would just remove all critical files from the repository, whereas I'd like them to be still versioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a submodule and share that.

Comment: This looks much more like what I'm expecting, thanks. I'm reading about git submodules and I'll come back with questions, if any.

Comment: If you are going to be doing lots of work with submodules, consider git slave. Also, if you feel up to it, take a look at sub tree merges. It may be more complicated than what you need though.